# How to check if View has received no results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry I didn't really know how to title this.
I have a webpage that displays announcements. What I cant seemed to figure out is whether there are any announcements, if there are display saying "There are no announcements".

I've tried stuff like:

```
if(db.Announcements.toArray().length == 0){
    return View(null);
}
```

but that doesn't work. Where do I deal with things like these? View/Controller?

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Remake.Models.Announcement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Announcements";
}

<h2>Announcements</h2>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{ <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <b> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                @Html.DisplayName("Date")
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AnnouncementId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Comments", "Details", new { id = item.AnnouncementId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AnnouncementId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

}
else
{
    <p>Please sign in to create an Announcement</p>
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: Announcements
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.Announcements.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: `if (Model.Any()) { // show announcements } else { // show empty message }`

Comment: @haim770 Brillaint, thank you. If you answer i'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model is defined as `IEnumerable<Announcement>`, you can simply use `Any()` to check whether it's empty or not:

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
    // show announcements
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else
{
    // show message when empty
    <p>No announcements</p>
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)